# The behavior of the cross validation error and training error in underfitting case is not clear

Tags: training, cross-validation, performance, bias

I currently study the "Machine Learning" course on Coursera.org by Andrew Ng, it comes to a topic that discusses the performance of learning algorithms under different conditions.
Here, we discuss the case when the algorithm underfits the training data (high bias).

[image]

I cannot understand why the cross-validation error (Jcv(theta)) decreases as we increase the training set size(m), and why it then flattens out. And I cannot understand why the training error (Jtrain(theta)) flattens out at some region, I understand why it increases as we increase m.
I asked about it in the coursera discussion forum and studied it twice, but it is still doesn't make sense to me.

Notice that :

- The cross-validation error(Jcv(theta)) is a measure of how well the algorithm fits the cross validation set, the lower Jcv(theta) the better the algorithm fits the cross validation set.
- The training error (Jtrain(theta)) is a measure of how well the algorithm fits the training set, the lower Jtrain(theta) the better the algorithm fits the training set.
- m is the number of examples in the training set only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason is the algorithm has very small learning capacity.

When m is very small, the model memorizes the data hence the very small training error. As m increases, the model is unable to learn the properties of the training data so the error goes up.

For the validation data when m is small, the model falls to generalize from the memorized data. The error goes down as m goes up because the model is learning the more general properties of the data.

This theoretical diagram is confusing because in practice most people would never use a low capacity model on such small data, thus would never see learning curves like this.

Comment: This answer helps elaborate things. The training and cross validation errors flatten out at some region because after some stage the algorithm will still give the same hypothesis even if we increase m. For the training set, the points missed by the hypothesis increase as we increase m, but we divide by this new m so in terms of "average" the training error is the same. For the cross-validation set, we do not increase or change the number of examples in it, we just increase the number of examples in the training set (m), so nothing changes as long as the hypothesis is the same.